# Setting Back Button Title in NavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to change Back Button tittle in a NavigationController in the following way:

In the parent controller I put this in `vieDidLoad`:

```
self.title = @"Calendars";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Previous";
```

But this controller is in the stack since I initialized the app:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

    navController.viewControllers= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aController,aBcontroller,nil];
    [window addSubview:navController.view];

}
```

So, the viewDidLoad in aController is not called until I select the back buttom the first time in the bController...

Does anyone knows how to call viewDidLoad just when I push it into the stack? Or do you know another way to change the BackButtom title?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the title of the back button for any ViewController you're in with the following line of code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Previous";
```

Comment: Just a litle note: In order to make it work as I expected, I put the code above in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: Note that you may need to set the title back to the original value in viewWillDisappear. Also, I can see the back button quickly change title after the animated slide, so this technique isn't flawless.

Comment: The property backItem in navigationBar is readonly. This solution did not work for me.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Comment: As stated before: put the line of code in override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { // here }. This works.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code to set up the title and navigationItem in `init`, you don't need to wait until the view is loaded.

Comment: This will work for the title, but not for the Back button.  It will set the backButtonItem's title to be aController's title rather than "Previous".

Comment: For some reason it only works if you create the button yourself: `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];`

Answer (score 0):

- Go to storyboard file select navigation bar of your ViewController set back button title under property inspector in Navigation Item > Back Button.  [Setting back button title to navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BloXs.png)